# Is there a way to have a method to iterate through a collection of sections and then call an element in that specfic section?

Tags: ruby, site-prism

I'm setting up my page object model and I have sections that have the same name but with an added index at the end of each. I want to be able to have a collection of sections that I can iterate through based on the index and then call an element in that specific section

```rb
sections :sizes, Sizes, 'div[data-hr-id]'
def size_with_id(id)
  sizes.find {|size| size['data-hr-id'] == 'sizeRow' + id.to_s}
end

class Sizes < SitePrism::Section
  element :sizeName, '[data-hr-id="sizeName"] > input'
  element :sizePrice, '[data-hr-id="sizePrice"]'
  element :sizeCost, '[data-hr-id="sizeCost"]'
  element :sizeDefault, 'button[data-hr-id="sizeDefault"]'
  element :locationOverride, '[data-tooltip="Location Overrides"]'
  element :sizeReference, '[data-hr-id="sizeReference"]'
  element :sizeDelete, 'button[data-hr-id="sizeDelete"]'
end
```

so that in my test I can call it out like

```rb
@items_page.newItem.size_with_id(0).sizePrice.set '5.99'
```

note: the sizes sections are within the newItem section on the items_page

Is this possible?

I get this error message

```
Failure/Error: sizes.detect {|size| size['data-hr-id'] == 'sizeRow' + id.to_s}

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for #<Sizes:0x00007fc5b66a7088>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

`Sizes` is a `SitePrism::Section` class and an attribute is not deligated to root_element here `size['data-hr-id']`. You can achieve the goal by doing the following.

```
sizes.detect {|size| size.root_element['data-hr-id'] == 'sizeRow' + id.to_s}
```

Long answer:

I'd rewrite the section definition:

```
sections :sizes, Size, 'div[data-hr-id*="sizeRow"]'

def size_with_id(id)
  sizes.find {|size| size.root_element['data-hr-id'] == 'sizeRow' + id.to_s}
end

class Size < SitePrism::Section
  element :size_name,         '[data-hr-id="sizeName"] > input'
  element :size_price,        '[data-hr-id="sizePrice"]'
  element :size_cost,         '[data-hr-id="sizeCost"]'
  element :size_default,      'button[data-hr-id="sizeDefault"]'
  element :location_override, '[data-tooltip="Location Overrides"]'
  element :size_reference,    '[data-hr-id="sizeReference"]'
  element :size_delete,       'button[data-hr-id="sizeDelete"]'
end
```

- don't use camelcase for methods in Ruby
- name section as singular `Size` instead of `Sizes`
- Search for more exact section locator in if you have any other div with `data-hr-id` on the page it will be also found as Size section

Comment: thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I have a follow up question though would it work if I had multiple sections like this on one page? So if I rewrote it as you did above and then on the same page had


`element :attribute, '[ng-label="Attribute"] > input'
 sections :attributes, Attribute, 'div[data-hr-id*="attributeRow"]'
   def attribute_with_id(id)
 attributes.find {|attribute| attribute.root_element['data-hr-id'] == 'attributeRow' + id.to_s}
   end

class Attribute < SitePrism::Section
   element :attributeName, '[data-hr-id="attributeName"] > input'
end`

Comment: Yes it would. But it would group them all as the same. if you wanted them different you would do it like so

`sections :shoe_sizes, Size, 'div[data-hr-id*="sizeRow"] .shoes'`

`sections :feet_sizes, Size, 'div[data-hr-id*="sizeRow"] .feet'`

`sections :box_sizes, Size, 'div[data-hr-id*="sizeRow"] .boxes'`